# How To Convert External Image URLs To Own Website's Uploaded Images Automatically?

Tags: plugins, images, uploads, media

I have a website with over 300 posts and initially I used to use external image URLs in my blogs instead of uploading it to my DB and using them.

Is there any way to automatically get all the external image urls on all 300+ posts, to be uploaded onto my website and use the uploaded media's urls instead of the external image urls?

To be clearer, for example, if I am using a Lion's image from wikipedia, with wikipedia's URL..... I want to automatically upload that image onto my website and use the uploaded lion image url instead of the wikipedia url.

Comment: a lot of people would call this "localising", that might help in your research

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin [Auto Upload Images](https://wordpress.org/plugins/auto-upload-images/)

Comment: Namecheap's EasyWP doesnt allow installing this :(

Comment: you can see the plugin's code and use them on your website with theme and plugin

Comment: can you tell me how to do this?